# Cannot achieve smooth javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, smoothing

I have been trying many different javascript frameworks like jquery, even animation specific ones like $fx and I cannot achieve the level of smoothness I want to achieve.

There are two examples of animations I have seen lately that are extremely smooth, either on the computer or of iPhone and iPad.

http://beta.jolicloud.com/
and
http://www.apple.com/iphone/

How do they achieve such smooth animation?

I have been making very simple ones like simple text going from margin-top: 100px to 500px with either jquery or $fx and it is jittery...

Comment: those are both CSS3 animations, not JS

Comment: Smoothness of animation depends largely on the efficiency of the browser's engine and the speed of the computer. Neither is under your control as a developer.

Comment: mblaze: you should make it the answer.

Comment: Another important aspect you should have an eye on is image quality. Higher image quality is inversely related to animation performance.

Answer (score 3):

Both of those sites use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions) and [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations) which are smoother than JS animation (CSS animation is based on keyframes and moves much more smoothly. JS animation is essentially *just*  the keyframes like stop-motion so it's more jittery)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery easing with your script for smooth animation. http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Answer (score 0):

Lookup http://jquerymobile.com/ for mobile optimization of your transitions,

Also, lookup http://api.jquery.com/animate/ to change from one state to another.

There are duration and easing properties for your "smoothness" :)